# How do I ground my power supply?

Tags: power-supply, power, power-electronics, basic

I have a Meanwell GST120A24-P1M +24V power supply (picture below).

[image: PSU]

I want it to power a circuit of mine. Say the circuit is as shown below: one power supply and one resistor. How do I connect the side connected to ground when I only have one DC positive output from my power supply?

Even if I would connect 2 split wires to the DC output they would still both have +24V wouldn't they?

[image: circuit]

Comment: You don't need to earth ground your circuit.  It can float.  From the circuit's point of view, it's like it's operating on batteries (your flashlight and iphone definitely don't have ground connections and work just fine!)     "Ground" in this circuit is just a defined zero-voltage reference point in your circuit. Its arbitrary.  You could pick any node and call it "ground".   It does not need to actually be connected to earth ground.   Yes, it's confusing!

Comment: ^^^    https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_ground

Comment: @KyleB Haha, yeah a bit confusing. I'm used to Power supply like the one in the picture, where there is a "+" and "-".


https://uk.farnell.com/productimages/large/en_GB/2361551-40.jpg

How about on a PCB where there is a shared ground plane. Would it still be okay to have it floating?

Comment: Can you measure the resistance (not the DMM beeper) between the mains inlet earth pin and the output connector V-, it's very quick to do. Thanks.

Comment: One more thing, there's no stupid or silly questions so don't worry. Only answers can be stupid :)

Comment: @VIPPER, very well-intended but not true :-) At any rate, have modified OP's question to not demean theirself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your output connector has a two-pin output connector, with +V (24 V) and -V (0 V).

See the below extract from its datasheet It states that V- is connected to AC FG, where where FG is Frame Ground.

In other words, it's stating that the -V is connected to the safety earth (ground) pin of the mains inlet. So you already have a ground connection on your output connector.

[image: datasheet]

You can prove these easily enough with the fully disconnected PSU and a multimeter measuring resistance. This is common with these supplies, such as those for laptops.

Comment: Ah okay, so the outside of the dc connector is "-" but inside of it is "+"? That means that if I want both plus and minus here I would have to connect one wire to the outside and one wire to the inside of the dc connector?

Comment: I believe isolated  class 2 supplies by definition do not have the PE connection, this is marketed as class 1 supply and is not isolated. I always assumed laptop chargers were class 2 but I guess not!! E

Comment: @crasic, many years back, I glibly connected a laptop serial port to a machine board, safe in my certainty that PSUs like this laptop's were floating. Then I watched it bang a track off the board. Bad presumption and bad engineering from me :-) A DMM showed the grounding through the PSU. Since then, I've gone looking for grounding in PSU datasheets like this brick PSU and generally buzzed through laptop PSUs when using them in labs just so I know.

Comment: I have had a similar experiences through multi serial ports and it is no fun to see magic smoke from your lab PC. Such a huge blind spot thanks!!

Comment: The power supply has certainly earth mains on input, but it is anyone's guess if the low voltage output is directly earthed, or floating, or something in between. For instance a box of power supplies I know simply measures 470 ohms with a multimeter, when measured between mains earth and output common terminal.

Comment: @Justme, the datasheet states the grounding, so it's nobody's guess. Have re-ordered my answer paragraphs so its clearer it's datasheet-led.

Comment: But having the V- connected to FG (=PE from the mains), as I understand you, would trip the earth protective circuit breaker as well as go against safety regulations (at least in EU) so I find it hard to believe that V- is actually using PE as a 0-reference.